# References for this inequality in probability?

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables, independence

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Let $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variables of this space which takes values on $\mathbb{N}$. We then define : $\begin{array}{|l}\  S_0= 0 \\ S_{n} = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^nX_k \ , \ \forall n\ge 1 \end{array}$.

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}^*_+$ and $\omega \in \Omega$ and let define $N_a(\omega):= \text{Card}\{n\in \mathbb{N}\ / \ S_n(\omega) \le a\}$. Moreover let $p,q \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $0<q<p<1$ and for all $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$, $\mathbb{P}(X_n=0)=1-p$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_n=1)=q$.

Hence for all $a\in \mathbb{R}^*_+$ : $\mathbb{E}[N_a]\le \dfrac{\lfloor{a}\rfloor +1}{p}$.

Is it a well-known inequality in probability ? Are there references about it ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I wouldn't say that the inequality itself is well-known. I can't recall ever seeing it before, although it's not the sort of detail I'd be likely to remember, even if I had. It isn't all that difficult to prove, however. The random variable $\ N_a\ $ is the [first passage time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-hitting-time_model) of the Markov chain $\ S_n\ $ into a state $\ \ge\lfloor a\rfloor+1\ $, and techniques for calculating this certainly *are* well-known.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Thank you ! It's interesting to see that this kind of statement is linked with Markov chain !